# Reading Doubles from a Scanner in Java not working out

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

**Edit: figured it out, misplaced a piece of code**

I have a program that calculates slopes from a file. The format the file is in is like this:

> Y2 'space' Y1 'space' X2 'space' X1 'space'

I am using a Scanner to read Strings from the file then converting them to a double or integer. The reason I am doing this is because it seems like it doesn't read doubles or integers from a text file only strings. Here is some of my code:

```
 modelSlopes.clear();
    modelValues.clear();
    int returnVal = openFileChooser.showOpenDialog(this);

    if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        File file = openFileChooser.getSelectedFile();
        try {
            Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(new FileReader(file));
            int count = 1;
            boolean suc = true;
            while (fileScanner.hasNext()) {
                suc = true;
                double tmp1 = 0;
                double tmp2 = 0;
                double tmp3 = 0;
                double tmp4 = 0;
                try {
                    if(count == 1) {
                        tmp1 = Double.valueOf(fileScanner.next());

                    }
                    if(count == 2) {
                        tmp2 = Double.valueOf(fileScanner.next());

                    }
                    if(count == 3) {
                        tmp3 = Double.valueOf(fileScanner.next());

                    }
                    if(count == 4) {
                        tmp4 = Double.valueOf(fileScanner.next());

                    }

                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {

                    try {
                        if(count == 1) {
                            tmp1 = Integer.valueOf(fileScanner.next());
                        }
                        if(count == 2) {
                            tmp2 = Integer.valueOf(fileScanner.next());
                        }
                        if(count == 3) {
                            tmp3 = Integer.valueOf(fileScanner.next());
                        }
                        if(count == 4) {
                            tmp4 = Integer.valueOf(fileScanner.next());
                        }
                    } catch(NumberFormatException e1) {
                        suc = false;
                    }
                }

                if(suc)  {
                    if(count != 4) {
                        count++;
                    }
                    if(count == 4) {
                        count = 1;
                        SlopeSolver tmpS = new SlopeSolver(Double.valueOf(tmp1), Double.valueOf(tmp2), Double.valueOf(tmp3), Double.valueOf(tmp4));
                        modelSlopes.addElement(tmpS.getSlope());
                        modelValues.addElement("Y2 - " + String.valueOf(tmp1) + "; Y1 - " + String.valueOf(tmp2) + "; X2 - " + String.valueOf(tmp3) + "; X1 - " + String.valueOf(tmp4));

                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Error opening or with file");
        }
    } else {
    }
```

When I do this it displays 0's for the slope and the values. I can't seem to get it to work. I am new to java, and I am pretty clueless right now. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the text file I am reading data from:

```
0.0 2.0 0.0 1.0
```

~Andrew

Comment: You need to apply basic trouble-shooting skills here and look at what your code is doing while it's running. Either use the debugger and step through, seeing what you're reading from the file and why it's not what you expect. If you're not familiar with using a debugger, add some `System.out.println()` statements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would simplify the code

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new FileReader(file));
SlopeSolver ss = new SlopeSolver(sc.nextDouble(),
                              sc.nextDouble(), sc.nextDouble(), sc.nextDouble());
sc.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `fileScanner.nextDouble()` to read `double` form the user input, and `fileScanner.nextInt()` to read `int`.

Comment: When I do that I still get 0's and NaN's